# I want to use the Python 3 post of requests to achieve the login but always 404

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my code:

```
Name = 'admin'
password = '213434'
data = {'Username':Name, 'Password':password}
url = "https://41.32.252.253"

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
resq = requests.post(url=url, verify=False, data=data)
print(resq.text)
print(resq.status_code)
```

Comment: God doesn't exist to debug your code, programmers do.

Comment: Pretty optimistic. I don't think I've ever seen God answering questions on here.

Comment: @khelwood lol :)

Comment: @tomchen Please describe what you want to achieve in more detail and then tell us where exactly you get which error (not just "... but always 404" in the question title).

Comment: I change the `index_username` and `password` but also 404. Is it beasue of https?

Comment: @Craicerjack it is UserName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post URL must be :

```
https://41.32.252.253/api/system/user_login
```

And data must be:

```
data = {'UserName':'admin', 'Password':password} #don't use keywords like Name
```

So your code must be like:

```
url = 'https://41.32.252.253/api/system/user_login'
data = {'UserName':'admin', 'Password':password}
resq = requests.post(url=url, verify=False, data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are god for me, at this time!  Thanks